# Pandas VLOOKUP for two dataframes with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have the following dataframe `df1`

```
    name           mobile_no      
0   Hector ABC       123       
1   Hector ABC       287        
2   Jose JKD         567      
3   Luis AH          NaN      
4   Billy DH         NaN 
5   Harry AC         569
```

And another dataframe `df2`

```
    download_date  mobile_no      
0   2021-05-30       123        
1   2020-09-28       287      
2   2021-02-11       789        
3   2021-10-06       321        
4   2020-01-15       569
```

I want to return the download date from df2 if the df1 mobile number matches. Doing a pd.merge somehow doubles the number of rows for df1. Is there a way check this row by row and return the download_date?
I cannot drop the duplicates (if any) in df1 and there are a lot more columns in df1. I kind of want it to be like an excel VLOOKUP that will return the selected column's result for that row by simply matching the lookup value. I tried something like:

```
df1['download_date'] = np.where(df1.mobile_no == df2.mobile_no, df2.download_date, np.nan)
```

Desired result:

```
    name         mobile_no    download_date
0   Hector ABC      123        2021-05-30
1   John DYC        237        2020-09-28
2   Jose JKD        567           NaN
3   Luis AH         NaN           NaN
4   Billy DH        NaN           NaN
5   Harry AC        569        2020-01-15
```

Comment: "Doing a pd.merge somehow doubles the number of rows for df1." Does it do that for this sample dataset? Can you include the merge code you're using and show how it differs from what you'd expect? Because merge left seems like the correct answer here.

Comment: @HenryEcker I used `df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['mobile number'])` and it did not increase the number of rows when I ran it in Jupyter Notebook cells. However, when I run a python script with the same code, it more than doubles the number of rows (same environment, same pandas version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df["download_date"] = df["mobile_no"].map(df2.set_index("mobile_no")["download_date"])
print (df)

         name  mobile_no download_date
0 Hector  ABC      123.0    2021-05-30
1 Hector  ABC      287.0    2020-09-28
2 Jose    JKD      567.0           NaN
3 Luis     AH        NaN           NaN
4 Billy    DH        NaN           NaN
5 Harry    AC      569.0    2020-01-15
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `merge` with `pd.concat`

```
m = df1.mobile_no.isna()
merged_df = pd.concat([df1.loc[m], df1.loc[~m].merge(df2, on='mobile_no', how ='left')]).sort_index()
```

#### OUTPUT

```
         name  mobile_no download_date
0  Hector ABC        123    2021-05-30
1  Hector ABC        287    2020-09-28
2    Jose JKD        567           NaN
3     Luis AH       <NA>           NaN
3    Harry AC        569    2020-01-15
4    Billy DH       <NA>           NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the order of df1?

Comment: `.sort_index` after `concat`? I still think this is the same as a merge left, no?

Comment: @HenryEcker yup. use `sort_index()`